# Creating a McCarthy 91 function that returns values other than 91?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The McCarthy Function is the following:

$M\left(n\right)=\left\{n-10\:\:\:\:\:\:if\:n\:>100\:\right\}$

and

$M\left(n\right)=\left\{M\left(M\left(n+11\right)\right)\:\:\:if\:n\:\le 100\:\right\}$

For any integers $n\:\le 100$, $91$ is returned. It's a neat function. Is there a way to adjust it so that it works with other numbers (i.e. for any into up to upper bound $r$, $M()$ returns $k$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix some $r $ and $k $ like you wanted, with $k < r $.

Let $d = r-k+1$ and then define your function as

$$M(n) = \begin{cases}
n - d, n > r\\
M(M(n + d + 1)), n \leq r
\end{cases} $$

Your function now returns $k $ for any $n \leq r $

To prove that works, you can use some type of induction. Start by showing that  $M(r) = k$. Then show that if $r - d \leq n \leq r, M(n) = k $. Then show that if $n < r-d $, $M(n)$ will simplify to $M(n_1) $, with $r-d \leq n_1 \leq r $

Comment: Wow - amazing. If you don't mind me asking, how did you figure this out? Or is this well known about McCarthy functions?

Comment: @ChrisT i do not mind you asking :) it actually took me a great deal of intuition and guesswork. Seeing M defined as M(M(n + 11)) pointed out the recursion and calculating M at some key points like 101, 100 and 91 made me understand that the way it worked was: when calculating M(n), if n is below $r $, just calculate M of a bigger thing. This hinted me that M(n) would end up to be M(101) for any number. After that sunk in, generalizing was fairly easy.

Comment: Very cool, this is hugely helpful and impressive

Comment: @ChrisT proving the function works is a rather interesting exercise. I challenge you prove it if you have the time and interest.

Comment: I think I could use structural induction or just regular induction to do so, I'll try it to better understand how it works

Comment: @ChrisT induction will be useful here. Start with your specific example and start by proving that $M(n) = 91$ for $90 \le n \le 101$.